# HTTP/2 on Apache (Ubuntu 14.04) does not work

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http2

I've tried many tutorials how to enable http2 on apache server; e.g.:

- http://pixelinc.co/ubuntu-14-04-3-apache-http-2-web-server-setup/
- https://www.gatherdigital.co.uk/community/post/how-to-setup-http-2-support/41
- https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/howto.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OM_eqRAsMM
- etc...

But without success.

Here is my configuration:

```
$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu)

$ apachectl -M
Loaded Modules:
...
http2_module (shared)
...
ssl_module (shared)
...
```

Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin info@example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName example.net 
        ServerAlias www.example.net

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1

        Protocols h2 http/1.1

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I'm trying load my page (https://example.net) in chrome, I can see this response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 12:05:08 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu)
Upgrade: h2
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 14:22:30 GMT
ETag: "b18-5367f99a49580-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 538
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Type: text/html
```

Am I Missing something? Can you give me any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 did it!

Comment: Doesn't really work as an answer for me :( I also use the ondrej ppa, everything is in place, but still serving over 1.1

Answer (score 2):

Define "doesn't work". I see the upgrade header so looks good to me.

I suspect a problem with HTTPS setup.

Either you're in openssl 1.0.1 and using Chrome ([which requires openssl 1.0.2 for ALPN support](https://ma.ttias.be/day-google-chrome-disables-http2-nearly-everyone-may-31st-2016/)). Check it in Firefox or Opera to confirm.

Or 2 you're using older ciphers which are [blacklisted under http/2](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#BadCipherSuites). Add the following config to force decent HTTPS config where possible:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+AES128:EECDH+AES256:+SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:RSA+3DES:!DSS"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've generated a lot's of different keys, but without success. I've update Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 and voila. Now it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1` to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` ?

This have worked for me.

Before it was only in the sites-enabled conf.